# nginx config error - PHP files download

Tags: linux, php, nginx, php-fpm

Whilst trying to fix a different issue, and clean up my config files, I've caused a problem. I have 2 domains binded to a site, but now, whenever I visit domain1, it downloads the php file as 'download', rather than executing it in PHP-FPM. If I browse to domain2 however, the file gets executed.

The weird thing is, they are both defined in the same config file. I must have changed something as it was previously working, but recently stopped. My config file for the sites look like this, (they are included from within the default `nginx.conf` file):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.domain.co.uk site2.domain.co.uk;

    root /var/www/php/hobnobs;

    # access_log /var/log/nginx/site-access.log;
    # error_log /var/log/nginx/site-error.log;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_pass        php;
        include             fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param       PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location  /common {
        alias  /var/www/common;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only presume that something was cached, I restarted and rebooted everything and after a while, it started working again. I didn't make any more changes to any config files, it just started working again.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when you visit the site1 you go, for some reason) on the default Virtual host instead of the one you have posted ?

Have you verified that when you go to site1 the access log of that VH register a new entry ?

Best regards

Comment: Urgh I don't believe it. Went to check something, and it started working again. Literally didn't alter a thing. No idea what happened. Thanks though